# how a filter is developed in e-commerce site

Tags: filter, e-commerce

I would like to know what are the required languages to know,  for developing a "filter" like in e-commerce site on localhost.

thanks in advance.

Comment: php, ruby, and python languages are the most popular languages for e-commerce. java language is used for larger enterprise applications.

Comment: ok thanks for info. But, I recently heard about magento to develop e-commerce site. ?

Comment: for every language there are open source e-commerce solutions. but your first decision is which language you want to work in.

Comment: Thank you very much. for advising me. :)